# How to retain the name of the current source file while doing a WebPack bundling?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-5

I want to be able to create an object that tracks back to the original source file. In the past I manually created them with different IDs:

```
   const TRACER = new Tracker('mySource.ts')
```

But the project grows, code being copied/pasted without changing the IDs and this starts to be unmanagable. I wish I could just have

```
   const TRACKER = new Tracker(__filename)
```

or something similar in every source file - no room for errors etc. Such boilerplate can be copied as much as one wants withoug breaking.

Node already exposes the property `__filename` - it is set to the current file being executed. It works great in dev. However, once the code is bundled by Webpack (or any other bundler) and run, that will be set to the name of the bundle. I would like to still be able to access the original source filename, even after bundling, not necesarily by using `__filename`.

Comment: When you bundle all your source files into a single file, of course `__filename` became the value of your bundled js output file. So the only file left is your bundle. Why should it be anyhting else? You take _n_ source files, and bundle them to a single output file. Sounds like a [x/y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), `__filename` is set during the code execution and not static

Comment: Yes, that's what is happening, but that is not what I want.

I am asking how to automatically replace the invocation of `__filename` with the string literal that represents the current source file.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This might be a bad idea.

Comment: We are monitoring the quality of the code in production environment. See the edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, found it. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#node__filename

In the webpack.config.js, I've added:

```
   node: {
      __filename: true
   },
```